# Need Assistance in find Min And Max from user input Array

Tags: kotlin, numbers, max, minimum

On the Android Studio emulator The user is required to enter a maximum of 10 numbers. When I put in the number 1 the output shows 0 instead of 1 (this is for the min number; the max works perfectly fine) Can anyone please assist me in this problem. I tried using minOf() and max() nothing worked Below is a snippet of my source code:

val arrX = Array(10) { 0 }
.
.
.
.

findMinAndMaxButton.setOnClickListener {

```
        fun getMin(arrX: Array<Int>): Int {
            var min = Int.MAX_VALUE
            for (i in arrX) {
                min =  min.coerceAtMost(i)
            }
            return min
        }

        fun getMax(arrX: Array<Int>): Int {
            var max = Int.MIN_VALUE
            for (i in arrX) {
                max = max.coerceAtLeast(i)
            }
            return max
        }

        output.text = "The Min is "+ getMin(arrX)  + " and the Max is " + getMax(arrX)

        }
    }
}
```

Is there anything that can be done to get this work?

Answer (score 0):

You're initialising `arrX` to a bunch of zeroes, and `0.coerceAtMost(someLargerNumber)` will always stick at *0*.

Without seeing how you set the user's numbers it's hard to say what you need to do - but since you said the user enters *a maximum* of 10 numbers, at a guess there are some gaps in your array, i.e. indices that are still set to *0*. If so, they're going to be counted in your `min` calculation.

You should probably use *null* as your default value instead - that way you can just ignore those in your calculations:

```
val items = arrayOfNulls<Int?>(10)

// this results in null, because there are no values - handle that however you like
println(items.filterNotNull().minOrNull())

>> null

// set values on some of the indices
(3..5).forEach { items[it] = it }

// now this prints 3, because that's the smallest of the numbers that -do- exist
println(items.filterNotNull().minOrNull())

>> 3
```